# jspx - how to add wordwrap in a jspx file?

Tags: spring, spring-roo, word-wrap, jspx

Using Spring ROO - I have a field in my JSPX file in which I set the range of characters as 15 to 200. So when the user enters a value with 200 characters - while displaying it is coming as a straight line instead of word wrap functionality. Can anyone please tell about how to add the word-wrap to the JSPX file.
Following is my existing code

```
<table:column id="c_Text" property="queryText" render="false" z="user-managed"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about JSPX but this can be easily done with CSS since it will be displayed in a browser.

Comment: I am using Spring ROO that uses JSPX. I would like to add word-wrap within jspx...